# Redistribute WSS 3.0 / Foundation 2010 with your custom application?

Tags: wss-3.0, installation

Let's say you want to build a custom ASP.NET CRM app and use SharePoint as backend document storage.

- Is it possible to redistribute WSS 3.0 / SharePoint Foundation 2010 along with your custom application from a legal perspective.
- How do you incorporate WSS installation into your MSI or any other package.

In essence, just like SharePoint can deploy SQL Express as database backend I am wondering if I could deploy WSS as mine backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of vendors selling SharePoint bolt-ons but I'm not aware of any that have hidden the fact that SharePoint is being used or that it needs to be installed first.  Surely it would be in your best interest to have SharePoint installed and configured before your app is installed.  It is possible to script the SharePoint install and configuration, but I'm not sure I would do it for this.  There are so many variables, and it may make it very difficult to connect it to an existing SharePoint system or later use SharePoint for another purpose.

Comment: Just to clarify: I am not trying to hide the fact we will be using it, just want to automate the installation procedure cause some peope will not know how to install SharePoint and give up.
Many MS apps ship Express as part of their installation just to make sure users are able to concentrate on app at hand and not worry about backend system installation.

Comment: I guess the best thing to do is test it.  I know the install and configuration can be scripted.  I would just be worried about the other variables.  I would be sure to offer the option of installing it on an existing SharePoint server.  I'm still of the opinion that the simple installs are not reliable installs and lead to more problems.

Comment: Yup there should be an option "Deploy to an existing SharePoint".